# Calling Java Web services in iOS/iPhone

Tags: ios, web-services

I have a java web service (WSDL,SOAP) which returns an xml (as string value). I wanted to know how to call this WS in my iOS program.

Is there any built in library like kSOAP library in android.

Please let me know if there is any relevant tutorial/sample code ASAP.

I'm a new bee in iOS!! :-)

Thanks,
Sindhu

Comment: well does not matter actually if it is a java .net ,pyton webservice as long as uses SOAP.Web services are for interoperability so that is one of the advantages of having them cause client implemented in other languages then the serve are able to comunicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no soap library in the iOS SDK. When you can, go REST. If you have to use SOAP, there is http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

Answer (score 0):

http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/2011/01/how-to-call-soap-web-service-from-iosmac-os-using-wsclient/ this can be good start for you.